# Dealing with path issues with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, include

I've just started to use PHPUnit, but I've run into a bit of a snag.

My code uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to compute paths for includes, which works when my apache server is the one running PHP, but `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is not set when I run phpunit from the command line with "phpunit Tests", so these includes don't work.

Am I missing something in the configuration of PHPUnit? Should it somehow be integrated with apache?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Late answer, sorry.

No, you're not missing anything. PHP CLI (PHP for the Command Line) is a different beast than PHP as an Apache / CGI module.

What you could do, though is change the `setUp()` of your files to set `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to what you need (since `$_SERVER` is still available as a superglobal even in CLI context), e.g. :

```
public function setUp() {
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../application";
}
```

Just be careful, you probably want to put this into your `tearDown()`:

```
public function tearDown() {
  unset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
```

[PHPUnit backs up your global state](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#fixtures.global-state) if you use global (also superglobal) data at all, which can slow your tests down dramatically, hence why it's better to avoid having any after a test has run through.

Comment: This definitely works, but why, if you can always use proper way to set additional variables thru phpunit.xml?

Comment: @TheGodfather Two reasons: One, this answer is from 2010 and much has changed since then, including what you mentioned. :) Two, you might want to set different values for different tests or testsets, rather than setting them globally, though this should be rare enough. So thanks for adding your answer to this question. I've upvoted it. I can't _accept_ it, but I hope the OP sees it and knows there are better ways these days.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of injecting hacks into production code or to test code, you can set up additional variables directly in `phpunit.xml` (which you are going to use at some point anyway) in `php` section:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">

    <php>
        <server name="DOCUMENT_ROOT" value="wwwroot" />
        <server name="SERVER_NAME" value="localhost" />

        <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Refer to [official documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/configuration.html#setting-php-ini-settings-constants-and-global-variables) for other possible options

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` can also be set in the Bootstrap file and the same `Bootstrap_test.php` is attached to the phpunit configuration file `phpunit.xml` with the attribute name `bootstrap=Bootstrap_test.php`

I was able to achieve the requirement to set $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for Jenkins job configuration. The "Bootstrap_test.php" looks like

```
<phpunit

   backupGlobals="false"

   backupStaticAttributes="false"

   strict="true"

   verbose="true"

   bootstrap="Bootstrap_test.php">

   <testsuites>

     <testsuite name="PHPUnit Test Suite">

     <file>PHPUnitTest.php</file>

     </testsuite>

   </testsuites>

   <logging>

     <log type="coverage-clover" target="logs/clover.xml"/>

   </logging>

</phpunit>
```

and the contents in `Bootstrap.php` is declared using `define()` function:

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));    
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = BASE_PATH;
```

The `BASE_PATH` variable will typically hold the full path to the Jenkins job directory. Say, Jenkins job name is `Test_Job`. The directory where Jenkins will place project source code is `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_Job/workspace` (assuming jenkins work directory as `/var/lib/jenkins`).

If Bootstrap_test.php is placed at the base directory, `BASE_PATH` will hold `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test_Job/workspace` and finally set to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to decouple your code from the use of the `$_SERVER` or any other global array. For example do

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $_docroot;

    public function __construct($docroot)
    {
        $this->_docroot = $docroot;
    }

    public function getDocRoot() 
    {
        return $this->_docroot;
    }
}
```

instead of

```
class MyClass
{
    public function getDocRoot() 
    {
        return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    }
}
```

This allows you to do

```
// in your actual code
$instance = new MyClass($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$docroot = $instance->getDocRoot();

// in your test
$instance = new MyClass($variable_holding_the_correct_path);
$docroot = $instance->getDocRoot();
```

Please be aware that this is just a simple example of decoupling. It might be much more complicated in your case - but generally it's worth the effort, especially if you'r running unit tests.

Comment: The problem then becomes, how do I include the file that contains this class?

Comment: Ah OK - I see the problem... I slightly misunderstood the real background of your question. You should not rely on including files using any environment variable (including `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`). Would it be possible that you include your files using relative paths, e.g. `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/MyClass.php'`? On the other hand you could set up some sort of autoloading...

Answer (score 0):

Just want to document **calling another php files** (like config.php) from inside PHPUnit tests.
I have a test class:

```
class xyzTest extends TestCase {

    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../../app/config/Config.php';
    }

...
```

In `config.php` I set up some constants, like file paths. These paths are relative to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.
I want to test my `xyz` class using these path constants.
However, the `$_SERVER` superglobal is empty, when calling PHPUnit from command line. I tried following the good advice from an [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683677/4636801) and set the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in PHPUnits `setUp` methods. This did not fix my issue.

I fixed it by adding an `if` statement into my `Config.php`, like so:

```
if ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) {
    $DocumentRoot = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
} else {
    $DocumentRoot = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'); //for PHPUnit
}
```

Hope this saves someone headache.